# Stereo calibration, do extrinsics change if the lens changes?

Tags: opencv, 3d, robotics, stereo-3d, calibration

I have a stereo camera setup. Typically I would calibrate the intrinsics of each camera, and then using this result calibrate the extrinsics, so the baseline between the cameras.

What happens now if I change for example the focus or zoom on the lenses? Of course I will have to re-calibrate the intrinsics, but what about the extrinsics?

My first thought would be no, the actual body of the camera didn't move. But on my second thought, doesn't the focal point within the camera change with the changed focus? And isn't the extrinsic calibration actually the calibration between the two focal points of the cameras?

In short: should I re-calibrate the extrinsics of my setup after changing the intrinsics?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should.

It's about the optical center of each camera. Different lenses put that in different places (but hopefully along the optical axis).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! 
It should remain along the optical axis, so it should also only influence the translation and not the rotation, right?

Comment: correct... if things were ideal. manufacturing imperfections, and any "jostling" of the camera when you swap lenses, _can_ appear as a slight pan/tilt of the camera. I am not sure if that can be "folded into" the camera matrix instead, and whether that's still a "camera matrix" then.